# Mockito NumberFormat mocking NullPointer in when() method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

so I've got this piece of code that throws me a NullPointerException

```java
NumberFormat formatterFake = mock(NumberFormat.class);  
when(formatterFake.format(1)).thenReturn("1");
```

The problem is I get an exception within the when() method:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.text.NumberFormat.format(NumberFormat.java:297)
```

I've also tried to mock concrete class giving me the same results.

```java
NumberFormat formatterFake = mock(DecimalFormat.class);
```

I am kind of new to Mockito and any help would be very apericiated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The format method is final. Mockito can't override it.

Answer (score 5):

### What's Happening

OK, so you're doing everything right here in order to stub a method on a mock.

`NumberFormat` is an abstract class.  This is normally fine, as Mockito can mock abstract classes same as normal classes.  The problem has to do with the implementation of the `NumberFormat#format(long)` method.

Taking a look at the source code for the implementation I'm using Oracle jdk 1.7.0 update 2, you can see what this method does:

```
public final String format(long number) {
        return format(number, new StringBuffer(), DontCareFieldPosition.INSTANCE).toString();
    }
```

The format method you are mocking is actually calling ANOTHER format method: `NumberFormat#format(long, StringBuffer, FieldPosition)` which resides in the same abstract class.  It is then returning the result of calling `toString()` on the result of **that** call's result.  It is a **FINAL** method, which Mockito can not stub.

When you use the when-then syntax to stub a method, Mockito actually calls the method you're stubbing (if it has a final implementation).  So when you write:

```
when(formatterFake.format(1))
```

You are actually invoking that first overload of the `format` method implemented in the abstract `NumberFormat` class.

The final implementation of the 1st overload of `format` calls the 2nd `format` method.  That 2nd `format` **is an abstract method** in `NumberFormat`.  So there is no implementation to call.

No problem, we're working with a mock.  Mockito supplies a Default Stubbing for every unimplemented method in the mock.  [By default, for all methods that return value, mock returns null, an empty collection or appropriate primitive/primitive wrapper value (e.g: 0, false, ... for int/Integer, boolean/Boolean, ...).](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html)

So when trying to stub the call to `NumberFormat#format(long)`, because it has an implementation, you end up calling the default stubbing of `NumberFormat#format(long, StringBuffer, FieldPosition)` which returns `null`, which is then `.toString()`-ed and there you have the cause your NPE.

### Solutions

Usually you would mock an interface, rather than mocking a class directly, which would avoid the potential for this type of problem entirely, as there would be no final anythings.  However, since there is no interface available here to mock, it is not an option.

You could mock the 3-arg overload of format directly: it should then allow you to call the one argument version of format as desired:

```
  @Test
  public void test() {
    final NumberFormat mockFormatter = mock(NumberFormat.class);

    final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("1");
    when(mockFormatter.format(anyLong(), any(StringBuffer.class), any(FieldPosition.class))).thenReturn(buffer);

    System.out.println("Result: " + mockFormatter.format(1));
  }
```

However, I'm not sure this is the best solution.  Maybe someone else will weigh in.

**EDIT:**

After seeing Garrett Hall's answer I made it more explicit that when I was talking about implementation I meant a **final** implementation.

As he suggests, PowerMock would allow mocking the final format method directly, if you're willing to go that route.

Comment: Thanks, this works well. However as you said it's a bit tricky, as I am actually mocking other method that I am actually calling. That does make a little sense to me. I thought that the whole idea of mocking is replacing the actual implementation by a dummy one. Why is the original code invoked at all? Is it because the format() method actually calls the overloaded version of itself?

Comment: @Andy Also, it is usually common saying to not mock types you don't own! And about your question, the answer is simple Mockito creates a subclass, and as you know it you cannot overload a final method, the JVM enforces this when loading / using the classes

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/) to mock a final method.

I'm not sure why you need to mock a final method on the `NumberFormat` class, that is a test smell.  Please post your test as well.